# Cannot connect to SAP HANA Cloud via Eclipse Neon Plugin

Tags: hana, sap-cloud-platform

I've opened a new SAP HANA Cloud tutorial,and I cannot connect to region host cf.eu10.hana.ondemand.com , and I get the following error :

> Make Sure your proxy settings are correct

I've tried the solutions proposed on SAP forum but none of them worked . Did you have this problem?

Answer (score 1):

As documented

SAP HANA Cloud does not support SAP HANA studio.

[2993439 - Statement on SAP HANA Studio and SAP HANA Cloud](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/2993439%20-%20Statement%20on%20SAP%20HANA%20Studio%20and%20SAP%20HANA%0A%09%09%09%09Cloud)

For administration, you can use the cockpit and database explorer tools which come with the service

https://help.sap.com/viewer/db19c7071e5f4101837e23f06e576495/LATEST/en-US/649092e9d9be41c59930179ce4f3d59e.html

Comment: I use the Modeler on Eclipse,not HANA Studio